# Invalidated Heap Upon Insertion. (Only in Debug Mode)

Tags: c++, debugging, stl, runtime-error, heap

**PREFACE:**

- *mNodes_* is a *vector* that contains a *vector* of *Node*'s
- *openList* is a *vector* that contains of *Node* pointers that point to a *Node* in *mNodes_*

---

I was trying to fix an crash I was having so I ran VS2013(The community version) in debug mode. However, it now crashes whilst in debug mode when it hit the following segment of code:

```
//If the node is not already on the open/closed list
Node listCheckNode = mNodes_.at((int)(node.getPosition().x / 32)).at((int)(node.getPosition().y / 32));
if (!listCheckNode.isOnClosed() && !listCheckNode.isOnOpen())
{
    mNodes_.at((int)(node.getPosition().x / 32)).at((int)(node.getPosition().y / 32)) = node;
    openList.push_back(&mNodes_.at((int)(node.getPosition().x / 32)).at((int)(node.getPosition().y / 32)));
    std::push_heap(openList.begin(), openList.end(), [](Node* lhv, Node* rhv) { return lhv->getTotalValue() > rhv->getTotalValue(); });
}
```

Specifically, the *std::push_heap*. Now, this isn't happening when it first hits this line as I know that there have been *Node* *'s pushed in before: [image]

I heard this can happen if I modify the heap directly, but I don't recall doing that. If you need more code, just mention it.

**THANKS!**

**EDIT:** I have noticed that I get this error when the item at the top of the openList(position 0) and the node have the same total value. Is a heap not able to contain two of the same key value? Can I create a heap that has a >= relationship between it's children rather than a > relationship.

**EDIT 2:** I have changed everything to a *std::priority_queue* that uses a functor that uses the ">" operator to compare. I still get the error.  <strike>I am almost certain that it happens when there is a *Node* * with a total value equal to one in the *std::priority_queue *</strike>

**EDIT 3:** Notice how 2412 is the total value for the current node and for one already in the stack. Guess what happened on the next iteration...  That isn't the issue

<strike>HINT: it crashed ;(. *▲▲▲ Illuminate confirmed ▲▲▲*</strike> May have just been a coincidence...

[image]

**PASTEBINS FOR ALL ☺**

*Zombie.cpp(findPath function):* http://pastebin.com/3YG2Nb2Y

*Node.h:* http://pastebin.com/nPMQdrrg

*Node.cpp:* http://pastebin.com/1fC3G9hx

Also, *Zombie.cpp* contains the following at the top:

`bool compNode::operator() (Node* lhv, Node* rhv) { return lhv->getTotalValue() > rhv->getTotalValue(); }`

Comment: Is it possible that `getTotalValue` doesn't return the same value all of the time?  `0xcccccccc` in your pointer values is troubling since that means you have uninitialized values.  Can you show a short complete example of the issue or at least enough code to be able to have an idea what's going on?  As you can see from [this example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/push_heap) a heap with duplicate items doesn't seem to be the issue.

Comment: That invalid pointer is there because there is a start node, hence it has no parent.

Comment: You didn't answer the important question, and since you have the same problem with another container I suspect it is important and most likely the source of your issue.  Is it possible that getTotalValue doesn't return the same value all of the time?  Without some code demonstrating the issue and the way you're doing things all you're going to get are guesses.

Comment: `totalValue_` is calculated soon after creation of the node. It is calculated by first getting the `distanceValue_` by getting the parent's `distanceValue_` plus an offset(either 1.4 x 32 or 32). The starting node does not do this and starts off with a `distanceValue_`, `heuristicValue_`, and `totalValue_` of 0. The `heuristicValue_` is calculated by taking the sum of `|pos.x - targetPos.x| + |pos.y - targetPos.y|`. The `getTotalValue()` function simply returns the `totalValue_` so I don't see a way that it could change. I will post a pastebin containing code in a second. Does that clarify?